# Error Creating Xcode projects for wxWidgets applications

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

I am trying to create an Xcode project with wxWidgets applications. 
I follow the manual of [wxwidgets](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Creating_Xcode_projects_for_wxWidgets_applications%20and%20get%20an%20error:):

```
....
 -lz -stdlib=libstdc++ -lwx_osx_cocoa_static -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker 
....

ld: library not found for -lwx_osx_cocoa_static
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea how to fix this?

If I look for the library the name is: "libwx_osx_cocoa_static.a"

Comment: Where is the library though?  When you know that you can add it to the *Library Search Path* so the linker can find it.

Comment: Did you build the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing! so simple: I added the library path (to libwx_osx_cocoa_static.a) and compilation succeeded! Add to `Library search Pathes: $(WXROOT)/build/osx/build/Debug/`